# GDB: Do not print output of .gdbinit commands

Tags: shell, gdb

I have set of a .gdbinit file to run commands each time gdb is called. These commands output a lot of stuff in the shell, and it's becoming annoying.

Can I prevent commands inside .gdbinit to print to the shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set logging redirect on`:

This is an example:

```
host: srv2-x64rh5-02, OS: Linux 2.6.18-238.el5>more .gdbinit
set logging redirect on
set logging file /dev/null
set logging on
file a.out
b main
commands
bt
info args
c
end
help
r
set logging off
quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other answer, I have these in my `.gdbinit` file that I use in other definitions and the cmd prompt:

```
define output_off
    set logging file /dev/null
    set logging redirect on
    set logging on
end

define output_on
    set logging off
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Yep, all of information, that have to output in the shell, you can prevent in .gdbinit
You can look at example of ./gdbinit from this guy http://reverse.put.as/

Comment: Could you please provide a more specific link?